# OpenGL Separating Polygons Inside VBO

Tags: opengl, vbo

I am trying to use one VBO to draw polygons separated from each other. When i draw the polygons, OpenGL cannot know where to start a new polygon and draws the polygons united.

How can i put a break point on VBO (or IBO) to tell OpenGL to start a fresh polygon.

Sorry it seems a newbie question, i searched for questions and tutorials but couldn't find the answer.

Thank you for your comments:)

I am trying to create a dxf viewer. Dxf files has polygons with solid hatch so i thought that it would be faster to use GL_POLYON rather than tessellation (i might have been wrong here).

My drawing function looks at each object and makes a draw call for every primitive in file. It looks that this type of approach is slow. So i decided to use one vertex array and one buffer for every uniqe type.

For lines, there is no need to know the endings since every line must have 2 vertices. But polygons may have different number of vertices and i should tell opengl where a new polygon begins.

```
void draw_scene(/*function variables*/){
    Shader::shader_use();

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    unsigned long int i;
    unsigned long int count = objects.size();
    for(i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++){
        glBindVertexArray(objects[i]->vao);
        glDrawArrays(objects[i]->primitive_type, 0, objects[i]->vertice_count);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    Shader::shader_close();
}
```

The above code hasn't been optimised yet. I want to draw the objects with same primitive type in one call. Thought that if could put them in one vertex buffer then i would be able to draw them in one call. So there will be one VAO for each type (points, lines etc).

In fact i don't know if there might be a better solution. Because even if i can put those in one buffer, then it would be hard to modify primitive vertices since they all would have been put in one array. Modifying one vertice would cause all vertices of same type to be re-read.

I also searched to bind multiple vao's at once to not to make too many draw calls. But i couldn't find a method.

Thank you very much for your help:)

Comment: Which type of polygon are you drawing. Triangles for example always use 3 vertices/indices per triangle.

Comment: Thank you for reply:) I am trying to draw GL_POLYON not triangles. So they may have 20 or 30 vertices or only 2. And i should tell OpenGL where a new polygon starts in VBO.

Comment: Show us the drawing code. You can't really draw polygons in modern OGL (and you *shouldn't*! Tesselate and draw triangles.)

Comment: You have to submit a draw-call for each of your polygons. glDrawArrays has a parameter where you can tell OpenGL where to start and how many vertices your polygon has. General note: GL_POLYGON is really old, slow and deprecated. If you can avoid it you should definitly not use it.

Comment: There's always the primitive restart index. I have no idea if it works with `GL_POLYGON` in practice (though technically it ought to). Unless you can guarantee that all of your polygons are convex, this is just a really bad idea.

Comment: I think primitive restart index is what i was looking for:)I think i should really use tessellation instead of GL_POLYGON:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part of this was already covered in the comments.

### Replacement of `GL_POLYGON`

The `GL_POLYGON` primitive type is deprecated, and not available in the OpenGL Core Profile. Fortunately it can easily be replace with `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`. `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` uses the same vertex order, so you can directly replace `GL_POLYGON` with `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`, without changing anything else.

Only convex polygons can directly be drawn with `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` without using any more elaborate triangulation. But the same was true for `GL_POLYGON`, so that's not a new restriction.

### Drawing multiple polygons with a single draw call

There are a couple of approaches:

1. You can use `glMultiDrawArrays()`. Where `glDrawArrays()` takes one start index and one size, `glMultiDrawArrays()` takes an array of each. So it can be used to replace an arbitrary number of `glDrawArrays()` calls with a single call.
2. You can use primitive restart. The downside of this is that you need an index array, which may not have been necessary otherwise. Apart from that, it's straightforward. You enable it with:

   ```
   glPrimitiveRestartIndex(0xffff);
   glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART);
   ```

   You can use any index you want as the restart index, but it's common policy to use the maximum possible index, which is `0xffff` if you use indices of type `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`. If you use at least OpenGL 4.3, or OpenGL ES 3.0, you can also replace the above with:

   ```
   glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART_FIXED_INDEX);
   ```

   Then you set up an index array where you insert a `0xffff` value at every position you want to start a new polygon, and bind the index array as usual. Then you can draw all the polygons with a single `glDrawElements()` call.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing GL_TRIANGLE_FAN and glMultiDrawArrays and also your whole answer:) I will try to find the best choice for my case among your two suggestions:)