# Draw unfilled circle with OpenGL

Tags: opengl, rendering, pyglet

I'm trying to render an unfilled circle in OpenGL that works with batching. Using GL_LINE_LOOP works, but when I put all vertices inside a batch to render at once, a straight line from one circle is drawn to the next. I couldn't find any good solution other than not to use GL_LINE_LOOP. Same with filled circles, I had to change from GL_TRIANGLE_FAN to GL_TRIANGLES and create vertices in little triangles from center of the circle and two connected points on the outer part of the circle. However, I'm trying to use GL_LINES and have two vertices that create a line, then add the last vertex again along with the next one. But I can't seem to get it to work and I end up with gaps inside the circle.

I can't find much online about drawing unfilled circles that work with batching. I'm using Pyglet as a framework for batching and rendering.

Comment: I suspect you're looking for something like [`glPrimitiveRestartIndex`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPrimitiveRestartIndex.xhtml).  If so, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26944959/opengl-separating-polygons-inside-vbo) may be useful.

Comment: Not sure how that would work in Pyglet

Comment: @Qlii256 The OpenGL tag is misleading. You are looking for a pyglet solution but not for an opengl solution.

Comment: @Rabbid76 In Pyglet I can use "almost" any OpenGL function that OpenGL offers. I know about PrimitiveRestartIndex and I could use it, but I don't see how this would help. I believe I need to use GL_LINES, but I can't figure out why they don't seem to connect.

Comment: And there's no other way to get batching to work without PrimitiveRestart? Because it would be a lot simpler to just use GL_LINE_LOOP as that's doing what it's supposed to do. Would this fix the connected line between the circles? Is this feature heavily supported and can I rely on it?

Comment: @Qlii259 pyglet links all OpenGL instruction. I mistakly thoght you are searching for s pyglet solution because of your comment "not sure how that wiuld wirk in pyglet"

Comment: @Qlii256  primitive restart is the proper way to go

Comment: So I would have to use index vertex-lists instead of the usual vertex list, right?

Comment: @Qlii256 you need an array of vertices and an array of indices.See https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Primitive_Restart

Comment: I can't seem to enable the extension by using: glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART). I get an error: pyglet.gl.lib.GLException: b'invalid operation'. Does this mean my GPU does not support it? Using print(gl_info.have_extension('NV_primitive_restart')) results in False.

Comment: I should add I'm using MacOS and the latest OpenGL version is 2.1, which does not seem to support Primitive Restart. So I need another way to "fix" this connected line issue without using Primitive Restart. It must be possible though?

Comment: @Qlii256 So  you have to stick it by linesegments. Actually you can use GL_LINES. A GL_LINE primitive consists of 2 vertices, the start and the end of the line. Hence you have to use each vertex twice, once for the end of a linesegment and once for the start of the next linesegment

Comment: That actually fixed my issue! I thought I was doing it correctly but I forgot to add the first vertex at the end. I messed up my loop a bit, but now have it working! Another quick question. How would I now do this for polygons/quads both filled and unfilled? I guess it's almost the same as the circle, right? Using GL_LINES and GL_TRIANGLES?

Comment: @Qlii256 For filled shapes you have to use triangles